# InvalidApiVersionParameter during file copy to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

We copy our build results from VSTS to an Azure Blob storage with a `Azure File Copy` Build Step. Since yesterday it doesn't work anymore but we changed nothing.

We receive the following error:

> [error]InvalidApiVersionParameter : The api-version '2018-05-01' is invalid. The supported versions are '2018-02-01,2018-01-01,2017-12-01,2017-08-01,2017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.

The actual state:

- The Subscription is still active and we can copy the files by hand.
- We have no possibility to change the api-version, because the vsts is hosted on visualstudio.com and the build step doesn't allows changing the version.
- We have no physically access to the VSTS.

Knows someone what happened and how to fix this? The api-version is named `2018-05-01` but it's still April. Could it be an early api update from MS?

Comment: Looks like you're not alone, did you see the workaround posted here? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/239086/vsts2017-filecopy-invalidapiversionparameter-the-a.html

Comment: @huysmania thanks for the suggestion, we will try it.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT sadly, we couldn't try it yet. The build steps are temporarily deactivated and i don't have the rights to activate them. But in the thread linked by huysmania, it is stated that this issue is fixed. We will try it asap and i will give feedback here.

Comment: It works fine for me without additional workaround.

Comment: What's the result now?